# Automake include all libraries

Tags: clang, automake

My directory structure looks like the following :

```
-misc
-- misc.h
-- misc.c
-- misc.la

-dict
-- dict.h
-- dict.c
-- dict.la

-main
-- main.c
```

I'm trying to build `main.c` into a program. `main.c` contains a reference to a function in `dict.c` and `dict.c` contains references to `misc.c`

How do I tell automake to include `dict.la`, `misc.la` to build `main` ?
In other words, I want to include all the *.la files that were built by the top level make.

This is of course just an example, in the real scenario, i'm dealing with more than 20 such libraries each in a directory similar to the above.

Answer (score 1):

### the recursive make case

You sound as if you were using recursive make with one top level `Makefile.am`, one `main/Makefile.am` and one `FOO/Makefile.am` for FOO in `misc`, `dict`, and the 20 other such libraries.

If possible, I would try to change to using non-recursive make for this use case (see below).

In that recursive make case, you will need to adapt `main/Makefile.am` to link main with all those libraries, and to make sure those libraries are actually (re)built if necessary:

```
bin_PROGRAMS     = mainprog
mainprog_SOURCES = main.c
mainprog_LDADD   =

mainprog_LDADD += $(top_builddir)/misc/libmisc.la
$(top_builddir)/misc/libmisc.la:
        cd $(top_builddir)/misc && $(MAKE) libmisc.la
```

You will need to repeat that `_LDADD +=` and build rule pattern for each and every of those 20+ libraries.

### the non-recursive make case

Personally, I would switch to using non-recursive make with one single top level `Makefile.am`, while putting both the `mainprog` executable and the 20+ `libfoo.la` files into the `$(top_builddir)`. Then adding a library to the main program can be reduced to adding a single line

```
mainprog_LDADD += libmisc.la
```

without any extra rules being required. This also parallelizes building of those 20+ libraries, which is a very welcome side effect.

The new top level `Makefile.am` would contain one line per library like

```
include misc/Makefile-files
```

ending with one line

```
include main/Makefile-files
```

and the file `misc/Makefile-files` would contain something like

```
# -*- Makefile -*-
lib_LTLIBRARIES   += libmisc.la
libmisc_la_SOURCES = %reldir%/misc.c
```

while `main/Makefile-files` would look like

```
# -*- Makefile -*-
bin_PROGRAMS      += mainprog
mainprog_SOURCES   = main.c
mainprog_CPPFLAGS  =
mainprog_LDADD     =

# repeat for 20+ libraries
mainprog_LDADD += dict/libdict.la
mainprog_LDADD += misc/libmisc.la
```

If your main program uses `#include "misc.h"`, you will need 20+ per library `mainprog_CPPFLAGS += -I$(top_srcdir)/misc` additions. If you could change that to `#include "misc/misc.h"`, a single `mainprog_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)` will do instead.

You could also include `main/Makefile-files` in before all those library `Makefile-files` and consistently add the respective library to mainprog in the library `Makefile-files`:

```
bin_PROGRAMS      += mainprog
mainprog_SOURCES   = main.c
mainprog_CPPFLAGS  =
mainprog_LDADD     =
```

with `misc/Makefile-files` containing

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES    += libmisc.la
libmisc_la_SOURCES  = %reldir%/misc.c
mainprog_CPPFLAGS  += -I$(top_srcdir)/%reldir%
mainprog_LDADD     += libmisc.la
```

If you can guarantee that all the lib_LTLIBRARIES built from the top level `Makefile.am` are to be linked to the main program, and that the main program sources can use `#include "misc/misc.h"`, the following top level `Makefile.am` will do:

```
include main/Makefile-files

# 20+ library includes
include dict/Makefile-files
include misc/Makefile-files

mainprog_LDADD += $(lib_LTLIBRARIES)
```

with `main/Makefile-files` being

```
bin_PROGRAMS     += mainprog
mainprog_SOURCES  = main.c
mainprog_LDADD    =
```

and `misc/Makefile-files` and the other libraries:

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES    += libmisc.la
libmisc_la_SOURCES  = misc.c
```

For a complete working example of a single library and a main program using non-recursive make for inspiration, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60306382/182675 and the [github example I built for that](https://github.com/ndim/cxx-automake-lib-and-main).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer!